# Local Apache server crashes when using mysql_fetch_array() and foreach() to display results

Tags: php, apache, foreach

So, basically what I'm trying to do is to display search hits on a page. I have set up a form which posts to the page below, this data is then searched for in my MySQL database and the results should be displayed in the following format:

---

Name

Profile Image Path

Age

---

I searched on the internet extensively and found out that you have to use a while loop, as I was just using a foreach loop before.

But my apache server crashes whenever I search for something. I think it could be because of the while loop as it didn't crash before but it would only display the **same** set of results (Name, Image and Age) a certain amount of times, depending on the amount of rows found in the database.

Here's the search page code:

```
require_once "lib/mysql.php";
```

if (isset($_POST[search]) && !empty($_POST[search])){

```
$search = $_POST[search];

// The mysql class used for functions.

$mysql = new mysqlHandle;

// Opens access to the mysql server.

$mysql->accessOpen('root', '', 'Portfolio', 'localhost');

// Sets $rows to number of entries (rows) with the 'Name' value of $search.

$rows = $mysql->tableCheckNum('*', stats, Name, $search, Portfolio);

echo "<div id='content'>
    <div id='content_main'>
        <h2>Search Results for '$search'</h2>
        <br/><hr/><br/>";

// Makes sure that there's at least 1 search hit.

if ($rows>0){

    // Sets the current hit number. (the first one is 1, the second is 2 et.c)

    $num = 1;

    $user = array();

    // My mysql function for checking the order of entries, see the attached myqsl code.

    while ($result = $mysql->tableCheckOrder('*', stats, Name, $search, ID, DESC, Portfolio)){

        // The $user array should hold the user's (searched for) details.

        $user[] = $result;

        foreach ($user as $result){

        // Makes sure that we haven't exceeded the number of rows.

            if ($num<=$rows){

            // Adds one to the number of displayed rows, as we have dsplayed another.

                $num++;

            // Prints the user's (searched for) details.

                print_r ($user[Name]."<br/>");
                print_r ($user[Image]."<br/>");
                print_r ($user[Age]."<br/>"."<br/>"."<hr/>"."<br/>");

            }

        }               
    }

}else{

    echo "No users found";

}

echo '</div>
    </div>';
```

}

Here's the applicable MySQL code:

```
// Gets order of entries (rows) The indentations under "function tableCheckOrder" isn't showing up btw.
    function tableCheckOrder($span, $table, $column, $value, $order, $mode, $base){

    mysql_select_db($base);

    $this->query11="SELECT $span FROM $table WHERE $column = '$value' ORDER BY $order $mode";
    $this->result11=mysql_query($this->query11) or die("<br/>"."Invalid $table CHECK ORDER query: " .mysql_error());

    return mysql_fetch_array($this->result11, $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH);

}

// This function checks amount of rows in table.

function tableCheckNum($span, $table, $column, $value, $base){

    mysql_select_db($base);

    $this->query="SELECT $span FROM $table WHERE $column = '$value'";
    $this->result=mysql_query($this->query) or die("Invalid $table CHECK NUM query: " .mysql_error());

    return mysql_num_rows($this->result);

}
```

Here's a pic of my 'stats' table structure:

[image: My 'stats' table structure]

I really want to be able to display the search results without it crashing

If I can give you any more information, please ask!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing"? Does the apache process terminate? What is the exact error message? Check the apache or php error logs inside /var/log/apache2/ for that.

Comment: The progress bar in the address/url section of my browser just stops, my computer starts to overheat and I lose connection to PHPmyadmin.

Comment: I think your in a loop forever. Also your doing something with $result. your using it again and again in loops. Dangerous.. You should change:  $users[] = $result; try that, but to me it's because your in a infinite loop.

        foreach ($users as $user){

Comment: check if the apache process consumes 100% CPU when you experience you r crash. Also, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement , your SQL/PHP mix is prone to SQL injection (hint: I search for `'; drop table stats; --`.

Comment: Thanks. I was planning on protecting it all once I got the basic code up and running :)